# Straight Line equation problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

> Show that the equation of the line passing through
>   $(a\cos^3\theta,a\sin^3\theta)$ and perpendicular to the line
>   $x\sec\theta+y\csc \theta=a$  is
>    $x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta=
>  a\cos2\theta$

My attempt:

I converted the second line to the intercept form:

$\dfrac{x}{a\cos\theta}+\dfrac{y}{a\sin\theta}=1$

Thus slope of this line is: $\dfrac{y\cos\theta}{x\sin\theta}$

And,

slope of it's perpendicular is $\dfrac{-x\sin\theta}{y\cos\theta}$

Using point slope form, ($y-y_1=mx-x_1$)

Equation of required line is:

$y^2\cos\theta - a\sin^3\theta y\cos\theta = -x^2 \sin\theta +ax\sin\theta cos^3\theta$

I am unable to continue from here.How do I reach the desired solution from here?

PS: I know $\cos2\theta$'s formula too.

Comment: What happens when you plug in for $x,y$ the values $a \cos^3 \theta, a\sin^3 \theta$ (the point the line is to pass through)?

Comment: Oh. I think I have made a mistake in finding the slope.

Comment: It's better to follow your solution from line's slope $\dfrac{a\sin\theta}{a\cos\theta}$.

Comment: Yes, I had made a mistake in finding the slope. I used Dr's method for the same and reached the desired solution

Comment: Your derivation doesn’t work for the case that $\theta$ is a multiple of $\pi/4$: you’re dividing by zero right off the bat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$P(a\cos^3(\theta);a\sin^3(\theta))$$ and $$y=mx+n$$ the straight line, then we plug in the coordsinate of P:
$$y=m(x-a\cos^3(\theta))+a\sin^3(\theta)$$  (I)
the given equation has the form
$$y=-\frac{\sec(\theta)}{\csc(\theta)}x+\frac{a}{\csc(\theta)}$$
then is $$m=\frac{\csc(\theta)}{sec(\theta)}$$ the searched slope
then you must plug in $m$ in (I)

Comment: this equation have i computed for you have you read my lines?

Comment: when $$m$$ is the slope of a line then $$\frac{-1}{m}$$ the slope of the perpendicular line